# Error al pasar función por referencia en php

Tags: php, revisión-de-código, depuración, paso-por-referencia, function

Tengo que calcular el volumen de un ortoedro mediante varios tipos de funciones que he de definir, y el único método que no me sale es por referencia. He mirado la siguiente documentación:http://php.net/manual/es/language.references.return.php

Mi código es este:

```
function &calcref($base,$altura,$anchura){
                   $productoref=$base*$altura*$anchura;
                    return $productoref;
                }
                $productoref = &calcref($base,$altura,$anchura);
                echo "El producto usando referencia es $product
```

Sin embargo, me devuelve el siguiente error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function calcref() in C:\xampp\htdocs\EjerciciosPHP\Practicarecup\PracticaJun\04_ejercicio.php:27 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\EjerciciosPHP\Practicarecup\PracticaJun\04_ejercicio.php on line 27

El script completo es este:https://pastebin.com/0z60PqUZ

Comment: Ya está arreglado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes mal tu nombre de la función cuando la inicializas

```
function &calref($base,$altura,$anchura){
```

Debería ser

```
function &calcref($base,$altura,$anchura){
```

Y así lo puedas mandar llamar en tu línea

```
 $productoref = &calcref($base,$altura,$anchura);
```

Y esta línea también está mal

```
echo "El producto usando referencia es $product
```

Debe ser

```
echo "El producto usando referencia es $product";
```

Comment: Uff, qué fallo más tonto, muchas gracias